# How to select unix time stamp from date field in MySQL with different timezone than server?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL server that is in `Europe/London` timezone and one of my table has a date field. The date is in `Asia/Kathmandu` timezone. I want to write a select statement to get date field as unix timestamp. Something like `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FEILD_A)` but this will convert `FIELD_A` to UTC assuming it as `Europe/London` timezone which is the server's timezone. I want the query to treat the datetime as `Asia/Kathmandu` timezone and return the timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(FEILD_A,'GMT','IST');
```

change IST to your timezone

FEILD_A should be date or timestamp.

Ref: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: thank you. In your answer what is `GMT` ? Is this the server timezone ?

Comment: Yes. CONVERT_TZ('field', 'from_time_zone', 'to_time_zone')